# How can we find the original file in case we create several hard links to a file?

Tags: hardlink

Although we don't need it much but still if we want to know the original file, how would we do that?

Answer (score 0):

> How can we find the original file in case we create several hard links to a file?

I assume that you are talking about hard links in a POSIX file system.

You can't.  As far as the file system is concerned, the hard links are indistinguishable.

---

<sup>OK.  Maybe if you created the hard links via a shell, the commands might be in the shell history.  Or the information might be in log files.  Or possibly audit files ... if auditing is enabled.   But not normally.</sup>

Comment: Yes, I am using a POSIX file system and I found that these hard links are indistinguishable. But I think the shell approach is incorrect. That's not feasible and proper way. @Stephen

Comment: There is no feasible and proper way.  Sorry.   The information is simply not recorded in the file system.